# C++ recursive array search for lowest index

Tags: c++, arrays, search, recursion

---

I'm trying to find the lowest index of a value within a range that is in an array passed to a recursive function.

```
int find(int arry[], int length, int lower, int upper){
    if(length>1)
        find(arry,length-1,lower,upper);
    if(arry[length-1]>=lower && arry[length-1]<=upper)
        return length-1;
    if(length==0)
        return -1;
}
```

function call:

```
int arry[]={9,2,6,3,2,3};
    cout << "Index is: " << find(arry,6,2,3)
```

This works to find the HIGHEST index value...but how do I backtrack? so when the function finds the value it flags it and won't override the return value with another one? I can't alter the parameter list to add a flag and I don't want to use static variables.

thanks!

Comment: `std::min_element(arry,arry+6)-arry`...oh wait you are doing this for hw aren't you?

Comment: Why the recursion? The values are not sorted, so a binary search won't work.

Comment: Looks like the 3rd `if` **must** be before the 2nd `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following recursive function

```
int find( const int array[], int length, int lower, int upper )
{
    if ( length == 0 ) return -1;

    if ( array[0] >= lower && array[0] <= upper ) return 0;

    int n = 1 + find( array + 1, length - 1, lower, upper );
    return ( n == 0 ? -1 : n ); 
}
```

As for your realization then it is wrong at least due to the first statements

```
if(length>1)
    find(arry,length-1,lower,upper);
```

Here find is called in vain. Its result is not used.